# Can't connect to MySQL server on MySQLCC ERROR 1043 Bad Handshake

Tags: mysql, windows, networking

I can't connect to my server221 with MySQLCC and also through my webpage. I have managed to connect to server 253 with no errors. I am not sure what is wrong but I keep getting the error 1043 bad handshake. I am positive that all my userID and password are keyed in correctly. I can even ping the server 192.168.0.221

I am changing PC and on my previous PC, I have managed to connect to the server221 flawlessly with the same settings. I don't know where to even start debugging. Please help.

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure the version that the server installed is the same as your ODBC Connector at your PC. For example is your server installed 5.7.16 MySQL. Then you have to installed the 5.7.16 ODBC Connector that comes with the msi file. Don't go to the web and download the latest ODBC connector. I will not work

Comment: Wish I found this 2 hours ago... Totally forgot about the version on this older server....

Answer (score 2):

This type of error comes with `Mysql server` 5.1 or older with versions, you need to update your `MySQL server version`.

Comment: Can you explain that further? The accepted answer shows another solution

Answer (score 0):

I had this message when trying to copy a table from one database to another on the same host using SQLYog community. I just had to restart the application in that case.