# Cant connect to Mysql server : ERROR 1043 (08S01): Bad handshake

Tags: mysql

I try to connect remote mysql server from powershell to 178.128.110.102 and i got error.

ERROR 1043 (08S01): Bad handshake

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49766838/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-mysqlcc-error-1043-bad-handshake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install MySQL Workbench from the official website"https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/" , this is the link from where you can download it. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the version that the server installed is the same as your ODBC Connector at your PC. For example is your server installed 5.7.16 MySQL. Then you have to installed the 5.7.16 ODBC Connector that comes with the msi file. Don't go to the web and download the latest ODBC connector. I will not work

answered on [Can't connect to MySQL server on MySQLCC ERROR 1043 Bad Handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49766838/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-mysqlcc-error-1043-bad-handshake).